# Crystal Reports using SQL query and generating an accumulated balance column

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

The following is my SQL query used in Crystal Reports.

```
SELECT     
    sum_date, sum_accname, sum_description, credit, debit
FROM
    sum_balance
WHERE
    sum_accname = {?acc_name}
    AND sum_date >= {?fromDate}
    AND sum_date <= {?toDate}
```

It is working just fine, but I need to get another column using credit and debit as an accumulated balance column (a balance column like on a bank statement). And while my parameters are working and the data is being filtered based on the dates provided, I can't get the actual balance it's calculating only the data which is between those two dates.

Is there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: do you need full data? not only the data picked by crystal reports query?

Comment: Need to display only the picked datas and a balance for previous data as an opening balance and a accumalator balance column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add a row to your query like this:

```
SELECT     
    MAX(sum_date) As sum_date, MAX(sum_accname) As sum_accname, 
    MAX(sum_description) As sum_description, 
    SUM(credit) As credit, SUM(debit) As debit, 1 As uNo
FROM
    sum_balance
WHERE
    sum_accname = {?acc_name}
    AND sum_date < {?fromDate}
UNION ALL
SELECT     
    sum_date, sum_accname, sum_description, credit, debit , 2 as uNo
FROM
    sum_balance
WHERE
    sum_accname = {?acc_name}
    AND sum_date >= {?fromDate}
    AND sum_date <= {?toDate}
```

With this query your first row, or the row that `uNo = 1` has the sum of older debits and credits.

Answer (score 0):

you can use previous function to get the previous days balance in crystal report.

to get the accumlated balance create a formula and write `credit - debit` and place after credit and debit columns in design.

If you need more info then show the design part of the reprot and where are you placing the columns.

Comment: accumalator balance column is a seperate column

Comment: is there any ways to create a formula

Comment: Right click on formula and create new